# Extract contents of binary file cocoa

Tags: cocoa, file, macos, encryption, aes

I am working on an encryption tool, and I need to be able to encrypt the contents of any binary file whether it be text or sound. How can I extract the contents of the file and use that to encrypt. I already have my encryption set, but it is of no use if I have nothing to encrypt.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way, if you can afford loading the whole file into memory is:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:yourPath];
```

Otherwise you can use NSFileHandle:

```
NSFileHandle* fileH = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:yourPath];
NSData* dataChunk = [fileH readDataOfLength:maxSize];
```

See also [NSData Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSFileHandle Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Great thanks. For NSFileHandle can I access the file within the application (to encrypt) at any point?

Comment: Also, I'm new to all of this, so please bear with me. In what format do I enter the path, so I can test? Sorry for such a nooby question.